# How to optimise code that parses a 2-d array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, multidimensional-array

**Note**: This question poses a problem that I have already solved, however I feel my solution is very rudimentary and that other people, like myself, would benefit from a discussion with input from more experienced developers. Different approaches to solving the problem, as well as more sophisticated methods and algorithms would be really appreciated. I feel this is a good place to learn how Ruby can tackle what I consider to be a fairly difficult problem for a beginner.

Given a 6x6 2D Array `arr`:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

We define an hourglass in `arr` to be a subset of values with indices falling in this pattern in `arr`'s graphical representation:

```
a b c
  d
e f g
```

There are 16 hourglasses in `arr` and an hourglass sum is the sum of an hourglass' values. Calculate the hourglass sum for every hourglass in `arr`, then print the maximum hourglass sum.

For example, given the 2D array:

```
arr = [
  [-9, -9, -9,  1, 1, 1], 
  [ 0, -9,  0,  4, 3, 2],
  [-9, -9, -9,  1, 2, 3],
  [ 0,  0,  8,  6, 6, 0],
  [ 0,  0,  0, -2, 0, 0],
  [ 0,  0,  1,  2, 4, 0]
]
```

We calculate the following  hourglass values:

```
-63, -34, -9, 12, 
-10, 0, 28, 23, 
-27, -11, -2, 10, 
9, 17, 25, 18
```

Our highest hourglass value is  from the hourglass:

```
0 4 3
  1
8 6 6
```

My solution is:

```
def hourglass_sum(arr)
  hourglasses = []

  arr.each_with_index do |row, i|
    # rescue clause to prevent iterating outside the array
    unless arr[i].nil?

      arr[i].length.times do |iteration|
        # generate n 3x3 arrays
        r1 = arr[i][iteration...iteration+3]
        r2 = arr[i+1][iteration...iteration+3] if arr[i+1] != nil
        r3 = arr[i+2][iteration...iteration+3] if arr[i+2] != nil

        # rescue clause to stop creating 3x3 arrays that fall outside given input array
        if arr[i+1] != nil && arr[i+2] != nil
          # take all values except indices 0 and 5 from the 9 element array
          result = r1 + [r2[1]] + r3
          hourglasses << result.sum unless result.include? nil
        end
      end
    end
  end
  p hourglasses.max
end

arr = [[-9, -9, -9, 1, 1, 1], [0, -9,  0,  4, 3, 2], [-9, -9, -9, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 8, 6, 6, 0], [0, 0 ,0, -2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0]]

hourglass_sum(arr)
# => 28
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @CarySwoveland. I've edited the question appropriately.

Comment: You don't need to define `arr` at the end as it's already defined earlier. (In general, try to format so that readers do not have to scroll horizontally.) One Ruby convention is to use [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for names of Ruby variables and methods (e.g., `hourglass_sum` instead of `hourglassSum`). You don't have to follow that convention, of course, but if don't, don't be surprised if you see an angry mob of Rubyists carrying torches and pitchforks coming your way.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, edited the code according to your suggestions.

Comment: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. Code for readability." — John Woods

Comment: I'd suggest checking whether "[codereview.se]" would be a better site for this or maybe more instructional in how to optimize the code. See  its "[On-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" information for more... information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [Matrix](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) methods.

```
require 'matrix'
```

```
ma = Matrix[*arr]
  #=> Matrix[[-9, -9, -9,  1, 1, 1],
  #          [ 0, -9,  0,  4, 3, 2],
  #          [-9, -9, -9,  1, 2, 3],
  #          [ 0,  0,  8,  6, 6, 0],
  #          [ 0,  0,  0, -2, 0, 0],
  #          [ 0,  0,  1,  2, 4, 0]]
```

```
mi = Matrix.build(6-3+1) { |i,j| [i,j] }
  #=> Matrix[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]],
  #          [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]],
  #          [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]],
  #          [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]]
```

```
def hourglass_val(r,c,ma)
  mm = ma.minor(r,3,c,3)
  mm.sum - mm[1,0] - mm[1,2]
end
```

```
max_hg = mi.max_by { |r,c| hourglass_val(r,c,ma) }
  #=> [1,2] 
hourglass_val(*max_hg,ma)
  #=> 28
```

`[1,2]` are the row and column indices of the top-left corner of an optimal hourglass in `arr`.

Comment: Readers: I expected `Matrix.build(4,4,&:itself)` to work, but it raised the exception, `#=> "...matrix.rb:103:in 'itself'; ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0))`. Can anyone explain that error message?

Comment: It appears that the method call you’re passing in as an ad-hoc block is being passed an argument, but the method ‘itself’ doesn’t take one. Basically ‘&:itself’ is the equivalent of writing ‘{|x| x.itself}’, but your example with a block passed in has two arguments. So the ‘&:’ shortcut builds the wrong code under the hood, and you get an argument error.

Comment: In most cases the elements yielded are passed as a single array argument and are implicitly assigned via array decomposition (in `hash.each { |key, value| }`) when a comma is encountered. If `h = {a: 1}` then `h.each { |e| p e }` will output `[:a, 1]` thus `h.map(&:itself) #=> [[:a, 1]]`. (1/2)

Comment: This doesn't seem the case for the `Matrix::build` method. It seems to yield two separate arguments instead of yielding a single array argument containing two values. `Matrix.build(1, 1) { |e| p e }` outputs `0` (not `[0, 0]`). Providing `Matrix.build(1, 1, &:itself)` will thus do `Matrix.build(1, 1) { |i, j| :itself.to_proc.call(i, j) }` which is equivalent to `Matrix.build(1, 1) { |i, j| i.itself(j) }`. Since `Object#itself` doesn't take any arguments you get the message you encountered. (2/2)

Comment: ...@3limin4t0r. 3lim's equivalency is particularly clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option I came up with.

```
def width_height(matrix)
  [matrix.map(&:size).max || 0, matrix.size]
end

def sum_with_weight_matrix(number_matrix, weight_matrix)
  number_width, number_height = width_height(number_matrix)
  weight_width, weight_height = width_height(weight_matrix)

  width_diff  = number_width  - weight_width
  height_diff = number_height - weight_height

  0.upto(height_diff).map do |y|
    0.upto(width_diff).map do |x|
      weight_height.times.sum do |ry|
        weight_width.times.sum do |rx|
          weight = weight_matrix.dig(ry, rx) || 0
          number = number_matrix.dig(y + ry, x + rx) || 0
          number * weight
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

arr = [
  [-9, -9, -9,  1, 1, 1], 
  [ 0, -9,  0,  4, 3, 2],
  [-9, -9, -9,  1, 2, 3],
  [ 0,  0,  8,  6, 6, 0],
  [ 0,  0,  0, -2, 0, 0],
  [ 0,  0,  1,  2, 4, 0],
]

weights = [
  [1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1],
]

sum_matrix = sum_with_weight_matrix(arr, weights)
#=> [
#   [-63, -34, -9, 12],
#   [-10,   0, 28, 23],
#   [-27, -11, -2, 10],
#   [  9,  17, 25, 18]
# ]
max_sum = sum_matrix.flatten.max
#=> 28
```

This solution uses the `width_diff` and `height_diff` to create an output matrix (4x4 for the sample data `0.upto(6 - 3).to_a #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]`). The indexes of the `weight_matrix` (`rx`and `ry`) will be used as relative index compared to the larger `number_matrix`.

If your 2d array always has the same number of elements for each sub-array you can replace `matrix.map(&:size).max` with `matrix[0]&.size || 0` to speed up determining the matrix width. The current solution uses the maximum size of the sub-arrays. Sub-arrays having a smaller size will use `0` for the missing elements thus not effecting the sum.

My solution might be a bit variable heavy. I've done this to have descriptive variable names, that hopefully tell you most you need to know about the solution. You can shorten variable names, or remove them completely when you feel like you don't need them.

If something isn't clear just ask away in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Without using the Matrix class, here's how I've done it for any arbitrary rectangular array:

```rb
offsets = [[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 0], [1, -1],  [1, 0],  [1, 1]]
sums = 1.upto(arr.length - 2).flat_map do |i|
  1.upto(arr[0].length - 2).map do |j|
    offsets.map {|(x, y)| arr[i+x][j+y] }.sum
  end
end

puts sums.max
```

The values we're interested in are just offsets from a current position. We can map out the values in the array relative to the current position by some row and column offset, sum them, then select the max of the sums.